# Adding global functions for kendo widgets

Tags: spring-mvc, kendo-ui

How could I add some global functions for all **Kendo** widgets in my **Spring MVC** project?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the function to the [kendo.ui.Widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget) class, as it is the base class of all Kendo UI widgets.

```
kendo.ui.Widget.fn.myFunction = function(){
   //custom logic
}
```